# Nginx proxy, linked to other docker containers

Tags: nginx, docker, build, proxy

I've created two containers running two different web applications. I'm trying to create a third container to have a nginx proxy redirecting the request to the correct container depending on the hostname. My Nginx configuration looks correct when I'm running the nginx official image, and modifying manually inside the container the default configuration file with the proxy setup.

My two web applications containers are already running, and I start the proxy container as follow :

```
docker run -i -t --link webapp1 --link webapp2 -p 80:80 nginx /bin/bash
```

To do the cleanest way as I think, I'd create a Dockerfile to create the container, and passing the local default.conf file to the container when building it.

This is my nginx proxy configuration file :

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.webapp1.ch;

    location / {
        proxy_pass   http://webapp1/;
    }
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.webapp2.ch;

    location / {
        proxy_pass   http://webapp2/;
    }
}
```

And the proxy Docker file :

```
# Set the base image to use to Ubuntu
FROM nginx:latest

# Set the file maintainer (your name - the file's author)
MAINTAINER Me


# Update the default application repository sources list
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        wget \
        vim

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY default /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
CMD /etc/init.d/nginx restart
```

But unfortunately, when I'm trying to build it, the container doesn't know yet the webapp1 and webapp2 container address / ip as they aren't linked yet. I receive this error :

```
Step 7 : RUN /etc/init.d/nginx restart
 ---> Running in aef974e80e74
Restarting nginx: nginx2016/12/29 17:07:17 [emerg] 11#11: host not found in upstream "webapp1" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:6
nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "webapp1" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:6
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

What am I doing wrong and would be the best approach to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using links is a `legacy` feature, you should use `User defined networks`.

```
sudo docker network create mynetwork
docker run -d --network mynetwork -p 80:80 -v /path/to/nginx/config/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf nginx
```

Then I used my recently created `user defined network` in `docker run` command.

Another thing that I did there, I `mounted` my `nginx config` instead of building a new image for it.

One of the advantages would be automatic `dns` based on container names in the same userdefined networks.

Now back to your `nginx` problem:

```
proxy_pass   http://webapp2:port/;
```

I'm guessing you are running all 3 containers on the same docker host, they all cant be running on `port 80` so you should provide ports in your `nginx reverse proxy` config.

Comment: Thank you Farhad, I've checked your answer and I've correct it by creating a network as suggested. It's now working fine